# How to load a css file with conditional in pug?

Tags: html, pug

I want add a css file in only index.html page using if with pug. I have got this code with pug:

```
- var thepage = { page: './index.html' }
            if thepage.page
                link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="../css/slider.min.css")
```

There are no errors with gulp but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below.
It works with  the parcel

```
- var page = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
if (page == '404.pug') {
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/cli/index.css")
}
else if (page=='index.pug') {
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/index.css")
}
else {
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/style.css")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally pug doesn't get a copy of the request inside the template, it depends on you passing it in from the route.  It's pretty easy to add the path though:

```
res.render('index', { "path": req.path });
```

Then you can test for the path in your template.

```
if path === '/'
  link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="../css/slider.min.css")
```

Given that you only want this rendered in one page it's probably even easier to put a boolean in your res.render for that one page.  This also has the added advantage of moving data/decision logic back into the route and leaving the pug template focused only on display logic (a very important factor in writing large pug apps).

```
res.render('index', { "includeSlider": true });
```

Then the template can look like this:

```
if includeSlider
  link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="../css/slider.min.css")
```